# CTE Multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query in oracle and i need to add 2 conditions .
I'm new to CTE.Please let me know where i can add the conditions

Query:

```
WITH cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN a.firstname IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END   FN
            , CASE
                  WHEN NVL(a.acc_no, b.acc_no) IN (1004, 1003, 1001, 1005, 1007, 1004) THEN 'newacc'
                  WHEN A.acc_no IN (1003, 1009, 1004) THEN 'newacc'
                  ELSE 'old ACCOUNT'
              END old_or_new
            , A.date_created
            , A.acc_no
            , A.country
            , A.organization
        FROM
            company                      A
            INNER JOIN contacts          C
                ON C.contactid = A.contact_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN org_contacts d
                ON d.contact_id = A.contact_id
            FULL OUTER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        business
                    WHERE
                        business_id = 1
                        AND business_agent = 'N'
                )                        B
                ON (
                       B.auth_id1 = A._auth_id1
                       AND b.acc_no = a.acc_no
                       AND b.bus_id = a.bus_id
                   )
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte1 x
WHERE
    date_created BETWEEN '08/05/2019' AND '12/12/2020'
    AND country = 'uk';
```

2 conditions

```
where date_created BETWEEN '08/05/2019' and '12/12/2020'
    and country='uk'
```

are not working properly which i have added.
Let me know where i can add this.
NOte: these 2 columns are of table company a

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: Define "not working properly".  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Are they not filtering the data the way you'd expect?  If so, examples of the data that is being returned and not returned would be helpful.  My first guess is that you're relying on implicit string to date conversion which is generally not ideal.  You'd want your `between` to use date literals or explicit `to_date` calls.  But no idea if that's your actual problem.

Comment: NO desired results , but I'm not getting error also but issue is where date_created BETWEEN '08/05/2019' and '12/12/2020' is actually not filtering. Maybe i'm putting this condition in wrong place

Comment: show us what you get as result and what you want as result

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but date literals are written like `date 2019-08-05` in Oracle, not what you have. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

Answer (score 0):

It took me so long to find out the culprit. Instead of   **A.auth_id1** You used **A._auth_id1**

Please try below query:

```
    WITH cte1 as
      ( SELECT  
                CASE WHEN a.firstname IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FN,
                CASE
                  WHEN NVL( a.acc_no, b.acc_no) IN ( 1004,
                                                                          1003,
                                                                          1001,
                                                                          1005,
                                                                          1007,                                                                  
                                                                          1004) THEN
                    'newacc'
                  WHEN a.acc_no IN ( 1003,
                                             1009,
                                             1004) THEN
                    'newacc'
                  ELSE
                    'old ACCOUNT'
                END old_or_new,
                 a.date_created ,
                a.acc_no,
                a.country,
                a.organization
        FROM    company a
                INNER JOIN contacts c
                ON         c.contactid = a.contact_id
and a.date_created BETWEEN '08/05/2019' and '12/12/2020'
    and a.country='uk'
                LEFT OUTER JOIN org_contacts d
                ON              d.contact_id = a.contact_id
                FULL OUTER JOIN ( SELECT  *
                                  FROM    business
                                  WHERE   business_id = 1
                                  AND     business_agent = 'N') b
                ON              (      b.auth_id1 = a.auth_id1
                                  AND  b.acc_no = a.acc_no
                                  AND  b.bus_id = a.bus_id))
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte1
```

Comment: thanks Kazi for your time .But I'm having issue in Date condition.as i'm new to CTE, i don't know where to put the date condition either in CTE body or final section where i call the CTE

Comment: I would prefer to put it in the CTE. Please let me know if you face any more difficulties.